# image of some ideal under the quotient map

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

[image]!
I am still confused about the range of $\sigma(I_{\omega})$.Since $\|x_n\|_2\to 0,$we have $\|x_n\|\to 0$,$\sigma(I_{\omega})=0,$then $J=0$,it is trivial.

Is my understanding correct?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not true that if $\|x_n\|_2\to0$, then $\|x_n\|\to0$.

For instance, suppose that $k(n)=n$, $x_n=E_{11}$ for all $n$. Then $\|x_n\|_2=1/\sqrt n$, while $\|x_n\|=1$.

Comment: Your example is right.But we have the inequlity $\|x\|\leq \|x\|_2$.I am quite puzzeld.

Comment: No, you don't. You are mixing the normalized and non-normalized cases.

Comment: Suppose $T\in K(H)$, is the 2–norm of $T$ defined as follows:$\|T\|_2=(\sum_{e\in E}\|Te\|^2)^\frac{1}{2}$,where $E$ is an orthonormal basis of H?

Comment: Yes, and $\|T\|_2=\infty$ if $T$ is not Hilbert-Schmidt.

Comment: So the inequality $\|x\|\leq\|x\|_2$ holds when in the non-normalized case.

Comment: Exactly. In the non-normalized case, it's just the inequality $$|t_1|^2\leq\sum_j|t_j|^2.$$